# QMap не работает

Tags: qt, qt5

Qt 5.6 Ubuntu x64

```
QMap <QString, int> map;
map.insert("key1", 1);
map["key2"] = 1;
```

В дебагере value

> not accessible

Элементов нет.

Comment: Дебаггер может не отображать содержимого мамы. Попробуйте просто принтовать значения мамы по данным ключам

Comment: @MalovVladimir действительно так и есть.

Comment: Если в Вашей функции только эти три строки и значение мапы никак потом не используется, компилятор может просто выбросить ее создание. И ни один дебагер не покажет значений.

Comment: @KoVadim У меня используется глобальная переменная, а это я попробовал в качестве примера. Переменная используется

Comment: Компилятор достаточно умный, что бы творить с кодом чудеса. Без полного кода сложно что то сказать.